# Can I use Cook's distance to detect outliers without a Dependent Variable?

Tags: standard-deviation, outliers, cooks-distance

I asked a previous question that I think was not worded well and long so I'm trying again!

I have 3 different tasks and performance for 20 levels in each task, therefore, performance for 60 levels in total. I want to exclude outliers before running correlations with these 60 performance measures and a few different dependent variables.

With excluding variables that are 2 or 3 SD from the mean, I could achieve this. However, my supervisor wants me to run a Cook's D and my understand is you cannot just get the Cook's D for each of the 60 performance measures without running a regression with a specific DV. This is a problem because either I run 60 regressions on SPSS and include the option to get a Cook's D or I run a test with 60 performance measures and receive one Cook's D. The problem is both of these options mean the outliers from Cook's D will be directly related to the DV. However, I want the outlier score of each performance measure to be independent of its relationship to the DV because I want to compare the performance score to multiple DVs.

Therefore, how can I run a more complex analysis like Cook's D that takes interactions into account without making the Cook's distance of the each performance measure related to one particular DV.

Many thanks!

Comment: 1. Cook's distance is a function of the residual.  2. What does it mean for something to be an outlier without reference to the DV? Can you clarify what you mean by "outlier" in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Glen_b . This is a good question. I suppose there might be a problem with my understanding. So this means an outliers needs to have reference to a DV. Without a DV you cannot have an outlier. So I am wondering if in this case the following is possible. I run a regression for each performance on each level to get the Cook's D. This would however mean running around 100 regression analysis with only one level at a time in the regression. I'm wondering if this sounds correct?

Comment: Well, perhaps -- the only kind of outlier you could mean is an outlier in x-space (which is why I was asking for you to clarify). But if you are doing a alot of regressions where your x's are the same you don't need to recompute the QR-decomposition of the X matrix anew each time -- so the regressions should be relatively fast. However your situation is not 100% clear to me right now.

Comment: Again @Glen_b thank you so much for being the only one to help with my confusing situation. Sadly I'm not sure what is meant by "an outlier in x-space" or "the QR decomposition of the X matrix" which makes me unsure if my answer will be useful here. It can help clarify my situation to you to start with. I have performance measures and I need to remove their outliers so I can run various correlations. If I put each of the 100 performance measures into SPSS regression analysis and tick Cook's D, I will need to do this 100 times which doesn't seem rightand I wonder if my approach is problematic?

Comment: imagine I want to regress some DV on height and weight but one person's height and weight were written in the wrong place (interchanged) on the form. Without my DV I can nevertheless look at a plot of the height and weight and see that one value is far from the point cloud of heights and weights (the x's, the IV's) and is an outlier in the space of the x-variables.

Comment: The thing with the QR decomposition is that regression programs do some calculations purely on the design matrix (the X-matrix) that are the same if you change the DV. Those calculations can be reused from regression to regression if computation time is an issue. It now sounds like that's not what you're concerned about though.

Comment: I see @Glen_b - so this means that I can look at outliers without a DV. This understanding helps a lot. And my second concern is related to producing a histogram and exclude values that, at face value, appear to be far from the point cloud of DVs. My main issue is that this method might be too simplistic and "lazy", and instead doing a more complex test such as Cook's D or Mahalanobis D might be better. So my main question was whether doing Cook's D or Mahalanobis D was possible without a DV? I feel understanding this last point will finally make everything clear and I'll know what to do! :)

Comment: Beware that you understand; this is not an outlier in the more usual sense. Outliers in x-space are usually called influential points and such points don't tell you anything about whether the point would be an outlier in the  sense of being discrepant from a model to the rest of the data, for example. In fact, considered in terms of Cook's distance; they're the part that doesn't involve the studentized residual. I already answered the question about Cook's distance, it involves the residual (just look at the formula!). Mahalanobis' distance can be done as an x-space calculation, sure.

Comment: Thank you so much @Glen_b !!! - You have been such a great help :DD

Comment: Hmm, I've probably said enough by now to write a sort of answer.